How to find the grid size from cell center coordinates
I have an octree computational grid as shown in the attached diagram.

The blue grid is a cube with a side length of 1, the red grid has a side length of 0.5, and the green grid has a side length of 0.25. The coordinates of the cell centers for each grid are as listed below.
cellcenters.csv
0.5,0.5,0.5
0.5,1.5,0.5
1.5,1.5,0.5
1.5,0.5,0.5
0.5,0.5,1.5
0.5,1.5,1.5
1.5,1.5,1.5
1.5,0.5,1.5
1.25,0.25,1.25
1.25,0.25,1.75
1.25,0.75,1.25
1.25,0.75,1.75
1.75,0.25,1.25
1.75,0.25,1.75
1.75,0.75,1.25
1.75,0.75,1.75
1.125,0.125,1.125
1.125,0.125,1.375
1.125,0.375,1.125
1.125,0.375,1.375
1.375,0.125,1.125
1.375,0.125,1.375
1.375,0.375,1.125
1.375,0.375,1.375

Now, I would like to automatically calculate the size of each grid from only the cell center coordinates and visualize the grid. I have written the following Python code, but the visualization result is incorrect as shown in the attachment.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

file_path = 'cellcenters.csv'
cell_centers_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])

def plot_cell_boundaries(ax, boundaries, color='b', label=None):
    for boundary in boundaries:
        x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max = boundary
    
        ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_min], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_max, z_max], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color=color)

        ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color=color)

        ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_max], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_max], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_max], color=color)
        ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_max], color=color)

kdtree = cKDTree(cell_centers_df[['x', 'y', 'z']])
distances, indices = kdtree.query(cell_centers_df[['x', 'y', 'z']], k=2)

cell_sizes = distances[:, 1] / 2

def calculate_variable_size_cell_boundaries(df, sizes):
    cell_boundaries = []

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        x_center, y_center, z_center = row['x'], row['y'], row['z']
        cell_size = sizes[i]
    
        x_min, x_max = x_center - cell_size, x_center + cell_size
        y_min, y_max = y_center - cell_size, y_center + cell_size
        z_min, z_max = z_center - cell_size, z_center + cell_size
    
        cell_boundaries.append([x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max])

    return np.array(cell_boundaries)

variable_cell_boundaries = calculate_variable_size_cell_boundaries(cell_centers_df, cell_sizes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plot_cell_boundaries(ax, variable_cell_boundaries, color='b')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('Cell Boundaries (Wrong)')

plt.show()


If you know of any algorithm or method to calculate the grid size from the cell center coordinates, I would greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you in advance.

Is there a way to add the level in the octree hierarchy for each cell as in x[i], y[i], z[i], n[i]? Otherwise it will be pretty complicated...

Dear Clement44
Thank you for your prompt reply! Unfortunately, I do not have information on the octree hierarchy of the cell to which each cell center belongs. Could it be that it is in principle impossible to identify the cell size with only the information of cell center coordinates?

Write the center coordinates in binary, and all will become clear.

Well, on second thought, I can think of a bottom-up algorithm:

Identify the minimal distance between two cells x[i]-x[j]: you get the size of the cells from the bottom layer of the octree.
Regroup the cells from that layer in octuplets* and replace each octuplet by its parent cell, which center is the mean value of the 8 coordinates.
Iterate the process with the new list of cells (which should have n(8-1) fewer values due to step 2), to identify the cells of the upper layer, and so on.

This way, you will identify the size of each cell of the original list.
*That part may be tricky if you have neighbouring octuplets, but you need to start from the edges.

Depth of a cube gives its size.
Size(0)-> 2, Size(d) -> Size(d-1)/2
To find the depth, take it backwards.
Say you have a center coordinate as 1.375.
Multiply it by two iteratively up to get an integer value:
1.375 * 2 = 2.75;
2.75 * 2 = 5.5;
5.5 * 2 = 11
1.375*2^3 is an integer value, 3-1 is the depth and the size is then 2/2^2=0.5

Assuming the size of the cube is an integer value.

@Clement44 Isn't it the case in OP's problem?

Indeed, I swiftly assumed it was an MRE, since no algorithm would be needed for such a small list of cells.
